# Type mismatch with List of class with generics

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

This is my code:

```
interface ClaseA<I: ClaseB, V: ClaseC> {
    fun otherMethod(item: I, holder: V)
}

interface ClaseB {
    fun getViewType(): String
}

abstract class ClaseC {
    abstract fun someMethod()
}

class HijoB: ClaseB {
    override fun getViewType() = "Prueba"
}

class HijoC: ClaseC() {
    override fun someMethod() {
        print("Some method, hijoC")
    }
}

class HijoA: ClaseA<HijoB, HijoC> {
    override fun otherMethod(item: HijoB, holder: HijoC) {
        println(item.getViewType())
        println(holder.someMethod())
    }
}

fun main() {
    val list: MutableList<ClaseA<out ClaseB, out ClaseC>> = mutableListOf()
    val hijoA: ClaseA<HijoB, HijoC> = HijoA()
    val hijoB: HijoB = HijoB()
    val hijoC: HijoC = HijoC()
    
    list.add(hijoA)
    
    list.forEach { item -> item.otherMethod(hijoB, hijoC) }
    
    println("Hello, world!!!")
}
```

I put an example code in a Kotlin Playground:

https://pl.kotl.in/BU0J-FkfR

I dont want to cast the item of the list.

The error i have when i press play:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is HijoB but Nothing was expected
> Type mismatch: inferred type is HijoC but Nothing was expected

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue with your generic variance here.

The beginning of your code may look OK:

- `HijoA` is-a `ClaseA<HijoB, HijoC>` by definition of the `HijoA`
- `ClaseA<HijoB, HijoC>` is a subtype of `ClaseA<out ClaseB, out ClaseC>` by definition of the `out` variance

However, the problem is that there is nothing you can do with a `ClaseA<out ClaseB, out ClaseC>` as far as the method `otherMethod` is concerned.

Let me clarify:

- `out ClaseB` means "some subtype of `ClaseB`"
- `out ClaseC` means "some subtype of `ClaseC`"
- the method `otherMethod` takes `I` and `V` as arguments, so in the case of `ClaseA<out ClaseB, out ClaseC>`, it takes "some subtype of `ClaseB`" and "some subtype of `ClaseC`" as arguments, ***but we don't know which ones*** (when seeing this type you don't know what the actual instance accepts exactly)
- any method can accept subtypes of its parameters (that's a general rule of inheritance)

Given the above, `ClaseA<out ClaseB, out ClaseC>` give us so little information that the only arguments that are guaranteed to be acceptable for the method `otherMethod` are:

- first argument: the subtypes of every possible subtype of `ClaseB`
- second argument: the subtypes of every possible subtype of `ClaseC`

Conclusion: the only generally acceptable type for both arguments is the type at the bottom of the hierarchy, which is the subtype of every type: `Nothing`. This essentially means you cannot call the method `otherMethod` in any meaningful way.

### Solution

You have to be more specific on the element type of that list for these elements to by useful:

```kotlin
val list: MutableList<ClaseA<HijoB, HijoC>> = mutableListOf()
```

Or

```kotlin
val list: MutableList<HijoA> = mutableListOf()
```

Note that you ended up with this problem because you are trying to declare a variance that's the opposite of what the `ClaseA`'s variance actually should be. It only takes `I` and `V` as *inputs* (method arguments), so you could declare your interface like this:

```kotlin
interface ClaseA<in I: ClaseB, in V: ClaseC> {
    fun otherMethod(item: I, holder: V)
}
```

This would have highlighted early on that there was a problem with the declaration of `list`.

However, if you have other methods in `ClaseA` that *return* values of type `I` or `V`, then you won't be able to use this declaration-site variance. You can stick with your existing declaration of `ClaseA` then. But you still have to fix the declaration of `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Your list is typed incorrectly.

Your list should be:

```
val list: MutableList<HijoA> = mutableListOf()
```

OR

```
val list: MutableList<ClaseA<HijoB, HijoC>> = mutableListOf()
```

---

Otherwise you are not compliant with the interface you have defined. By defining the MutableList as:

```
val list: MutableList<ClaseA<out ClaseB, out ClaseC>> = mutableListOf()
```

It is not actually a super-type of the HijoA class, because the out limits the contract more than the definition of the HijoA class signature does.

You cannot use `out` in this case, because you are receiving the generics as function parameters. If you never return the values, you could call them `in` but then you are again limiting the contract by only allowing downstream implementations, via contravariance.

Comment: I define the list that way, because i want a list with other childs of ClaseA with generics that are chlids of ClaseB and ClaseC.

If i dont put the out, i cant added to the list.

So.. there is no way of doing that in kotlin?

In java i can make a List<ClaseA> without definig the generics

Comment: @DejaVu *i want a list with other childs of ClaseA with generics that are chlids of ClaseB and ClaseC* - you're trying to call `otherMethod` on every element of that list with a `HijoB` and `HijoC` parameters. If the other elements accept other types as parameters, it cannot work.

Comment: @DejaVu *In java i can make a List<ClaseA> without definig the generics* - Java is broken in this respect, it will allow you to do things that will fail at runtime or pollute the heap.

Comment: @Joffrey _you're trying to call otherMethod on every element of that list with a HijoB and HijoC parameters. If the other elements accept other types as parameters, it cannot work._ 

I know. but HijoB and HijoC inherits of ClaseB and ClaseC. The definition of the `otherMethod` is with a parameter of ClaseB and ClaseC

Comment: @DejaVu Please read my answer for more details, but essentially the parameters of `otherMethod` are unspecified because of the `out`. They could be ***any subtype*** of `ClaseB` and `ClaseC`. You don't get to choose on the call site, the instance defines what it accepts. For instance `hijoA.otherMethod()` only accepts `HijoB` and `HijoC` (or subtypes), so you would not be able to provide other subtypes of `ClaseB` and `ClaseC` that are not subtypes of `HijoB` and `HijoC` themselves